# Selecting multiple rows based on foreign key in other table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have tables `Boys` and `Girls`:

```
Boys
id   | name
------------
1    | Bobby
2    | Timmy

Girls
id   | name
------------
1    | Mary
2    | Sally
```

I then have a table called Friendships, that holds a foreign key for the id of one boy and one girl.

```
Friendships
id   | boy_id | girl_id
-----------------------
1    | 2      | 2
1    | 2      | 1
```

How can I write a select statement that will return a set of Girls, based on friendships where the boy_id is 2?

Comment: This is a pretty basic `join`.  What have you tried?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm new to relational databases, join is exactly the keyword I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways. Nested query:

```
select *
from Girls g
where g.id in (
    select f.girl_id
    from Friendships f
    where f.boy_id = 2
)
```

Or join:

```
select *
from Girls g
inner join Friendships f on g.id = f.girl_id
where f.boy_id = 2
```